# Get unique data from list of result

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, partition

I have data something like this.

Original Data: 
1 -> A -> 1 -> 2011 -> 2009 
2 -> A -> 1 -> 2011 -> 2010 
3 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2008 
4 -> B -> 1 -> 2009 -> 2009 
5 -> A -> 2 -> 2008 -> 2009 
6 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2011

Step 1: Partition by column2. 
1 -> A -> 1 -> 2011 -> 2009 
2 -> A -> 1 -> 2011 -> 2010 
5 -> A -> 2 -> 2008 -> 2009 
3 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2008 
4 -> B -> 1 -> 2009 -> 2009 
6 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2011

Step 2 : Apply sorting by column3(descending) and If unique record found at first position return that result else apply next sorting criteria on only ambiguous record i.e repeat Step #2. 
5 -> A -> **2** -> 2008 -> 2009  **//Unique Record** 
1 -> A -> **1** -> 2011 -> 2009 
2 -> A -> 1 -> 2011 -> 2010 
3 -> B -> **1** -> 2008 -> 2008 
4 -> B -> **1** -> 2009 -> 2009 
6 -> B -> **1** -> 2008 -> 2011

So now Our result will be something like this.
List 1: 
5 -> A -> 2 -> 2008 -> 2009

List 2: Since we already able to find unique record in "A" so remove its data from remaining list 
3 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2008 
4 -> B -> 1 -> 2009 -> 2009 
6 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2011

Step 3 : Apply next sorting criteria i.e. column4(descending) but data at position 1 is ambiguous 
3 -> B -> 1 -> **2008** -> 2008 
6 -> B -> 1 -> **2008** -> 2011 
4 -> B -> 1 -> 2009 -> 2009

Step 4: Apply next sorting criteria on ambiguous result only i.e. column5(descending) 
6 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> **2011**  **//Unique record** 
3 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> **2008**

So final list will contains the result as below. 
5 -> A -> 2 -> 2008 -> 2009 
6 -> B -> 1 -> 2008 -> 2011

So I want to get unique data from result after applying each sorting criteria. I don't know whether I am able to explain my problem in better way and I know by using for loop and comparing data I could resolve It but just need assistance to solve It best possible way.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected results for those sample inputs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq with this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class SortOrder
    {
    public Func<DataRec, object> PropName { get; set; }
    public bool Ascending { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRec
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public int Year1 { get; set; }
        public int Year2 { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List<DataRec> myData = new List<DataRec>();

        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 1, Name = "A", Order = 1, Year1 = 2011, Year2 = 2009 });
        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 2, Name = "A", Order = 1, Year1 = 2011, Year2 = 2010 });
        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 3, Name = "B", Order = 1, Year1 = 2008, Year2 = 2008 });
        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 4, Name = "B", Order = 1, Year1 = 2009, Year2 = 2009 });
        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 5, Name = "A", Order = 2, Year1 = 2008, Year2 = 2009 });
        myData.Add(new DataRec() { ID = 6, Name = "B", Order = 1, Year1 = 2008, Year2 = 2011 });

        //var orderedData = myData.GroupBy(x=>x.Name, (key, group) =>group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Order).ThenBy(x => x.Year1).ThenByDescending(x => x.Year2).First()).ToList();
        List<SortOrder> sorting = new List<SortOrder>();
        sorting.Add(new SortOrder() { PropName = x => x.Order, Ascending = false });
        sorting.Add(new SortOrder() { PropName = x => x.Year1, Ascending = true });
        sorting.Add(new SortOrder() { PropName = x => x.Year2, Ascending = false });

        var orderedData = myData.GroupBy(x=>x.Name);

        IOrderedEnumerable<DataRec> sorted;
        List<DataRec> result = new List<DataRec>();

        foreach (var oneGroup in orderedData)
        {
            sorted = null;
            foreach (SortOrder oneSort in sorting)
            {
                if (sorted == null)
                {
                    sorted = oneSort.Ascending ? oneGroup.OrderBy(oneSort.PropName) : oneGroup.OrderByDescending(oneSort.PropName);                      
                }
                else
                {
                    sorted = oneSort.Ascending ? sorted.ThenBy(oneSort.PropName): sorted.ThenByDescending(oneSort.PropName);
                }
            }
            result.Add(sorted.First());
        }
    }
```

First I group (you call it partision), then I sort to your needs, made it dynamic and get the first records.

Comment: Looks great however sequence of order should depends upon user input so any idea how to create order sequence dynamically for the same, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please confirm if answer is ok.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best possible way, that is one involving least amount of loops is this way:

You need a LINQ group on Column 2 (Step 1: Partition by column 2. )

This will give you an anonymous list of two groups containing all the elements of A in group[0] and elements of B in group[1].

So you need to loop on the array of groups and take the first element after applying a sort on column 3 descending then by column 4 descending then by column 5. The important part here is the ThenBy.

So it basically boils down to:

```
For each objGroup in dtb.Group(....)
objGroup.OrderByDescending(Column3)
.ThenByDescending(Column4)
.ThenByDescending(Column5).
```

Let me know if you need the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a class like the following to represent your data

```
public class TestClass
    {
        private int _col1;
        private char _col2;
        private int _col3;
        private int _col4;
        private int _col5;

        public TestClass(int c1, char c2, int c3, int c4, int c5)
        {
            _col1 = c1;
            _col2 = c2;
            _col3 = c3;
            _col4 = c4;
            _col5 = c5;
        }

        public int Col1
        {
            get { return _col1; }
            set { _col1 = value; }
        }

        public char Col2
        {
            get { return _col2; }
            set { _col2 = value; }
        }

        public int Col3
        {
            get { return _col3; }
            set { _col3 = value; }
        }

        public int Col4
        {
            get { return _col4; }
            set { _col4 = value; }
        }

        public int Col5
        {
            get { return _col5; }
            set { _col5 = value; }
        }
    }
```

Then I wrote this program that seems to do in a certain what you are looking for

```
List<TestClass> test = new List<TestClass>();

            test.Add(new TestClass(1, 'A', 1, 2011, 2009));
            test.Add(new TestClass(2, 'A', 1, 2011, 2010));
            test.Add(new TestClass(3, 'B', 1, 2008, 2008));
            test.Add(new TestClass(4, 'B', 1, 2009, 2009));
            test.Add(new TestClass(5, 'A', 2, 2008, 2009));
            test.Add(new TestClass(6, 'B', 1, 2008, 2011));

            var first_ordered = from t in test
                                orderby t.Col2, t.Col3 descending, t.Col4 descending, t.Col5 descending
                                group new { t.Col1, t.Col3, t.Col4, t.Col5 } by t.Col2 into p
                                select new
                                {
                                    Col1 = p.First().Col1,
                                    Col2 = p.Key,
                                    Col3 = p.First().Col3,
                                    Col4 = p.First().Col4,
                                    Col5 = p.First().Col5
                                };

            foreach(var f in first_ordered) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{f.Col1}, {f.Col2}, {f.Col3}, {f.Col4}, {f.Col5}");
            }
```

It works for the 'A' partition, for the 'B' no, but there is something in your explanation that it doesn't seem to be correct: when you describe step 3 in the text you're asking for column 4 ordered descending, but in the data you put you ordered them ascending. So, I followed the text you wrote, if you want ascending order you have just to take my code, delete "descending" in the orderby clause and automatically Linq will order the mentioned field ascending.
I hope it helps!